Finding all 1-d arrays within a numpy array
Given a numpy array of dimension n with each direction having length m, I would like to iterate through all 1-dimensional arrays of length m.
For example, consider:
import numpy as np
x = np.identity(4)
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])

then I would like to find all all 1-dimensional arrays with length 4.  So the result should include all 4 rows, all 4 columns, and the 2 diagonals:
[x[i,:] for i in range(4)] + [x[:,i] for i in range(4)] + [np.array([x[i,i] for i in range(4)])] + [np.array([x[3-i,i] for i in range(4)])]

It's unclear to me how to generalize this to higher dimensional arrays since the position of the ":" in the slice needs to iterate as well.  In a higher dimensional analogue with
slices = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
we can get
[x[i,j,:] for (i,j) in slices]

but then I'm not sure how to proceed to iterate through the permutations of [i,j,:].

Should the result be 1D views or n-1-D views? In general, you can probably simplify the issue by moving the axes to the front/back with np.rollaxis, np.permute_dims etc.

In the 3d case (n=3), which "diagonals" should be included? With a cube, there are now way more: the ones "through 2d space" as from the 2d case, but in each possible 2d slice through the cube, but then also the ones connecting the corners of the cube "through 3d space" (there are 4 of them: from (0,0,0) to (p,p,p), from (0,0,p) to (p,p,0), from (0,p,0) to (p,0,p), from (0,p,p) to (p,0,0), where p=m-1). Should they all be included? This becomes ever more complicated with more dimensions.

Ah, or did I get this wrong? So just to be clear: for the n-dimensional case with n>2, do you still want to find all 1-d arrays, or do you want to find all (n-1)-d arrays? @Homer512 I just realized you asked the same.

@simon Yes all diagonals should be included - For a cube of side length 3, we want all arrays of length 3, so you have 22 diagonals in that case. The diagonals will likely be difficult to describe in higher dimensions and my use case my pivot to avoid that if it becomes too difficult to manage, but the permutations of the slices is currently my issue.

Although the comprehensions are readable, for large arrays you probably want to use what numpy gives you:
import numpy as np

n = 4
# random n*n numpy array
arr = np.random.rand(n, n)
print(arr)

# this has all the data you need, relatively efficiently - but not in 1D shape
result = (
    np.vsplit(arr, n) +
    np.hsplit(arr, n) + 
    [arr.diagonal()] +
    [arr[np.arange(n), np.arange(n - 1, -1, -1)]]
)

# you can just flatten them as you used them:
for xs in result:
    print(xs.ravel())

# or flatten them into a new result:
result_1d = [xs.ravel() for xs in result]

Edit: user @Matt correctly pointed out in the comments that this solution only works for the case of a 2-dimensional array.
Things get a bit more complicated for an arbitrary number of dimensions n with size m across all dimensions. This works, but given the complexity, can probably be improved upon for simplicity:
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

# random n*n numpy array
m = 2
n = 3
arr = np.random.rand(*([m] * n))
print(arr)


def get_all_lines(arr):
    ndim = arr.ndim
    size = arr.shape[0]  # assuming the same size for all dimensions
    # generate each 1d slice along and across each axis
    for fixed in it.product(range(size), repeat=ndim - 1):
        for axis in range(ndim):
            yield arr[fixed[:axis] + (slice(None, ),) + fixed[axis:]]
    # generate each 1d diagonal for each combination of axes
    for d_dim in range(2, ndim+1):  # d_dim is the number of varying axes
        for fixed in it.product(range(size), repeat=(ndim - d_dim)):  # fixed indices for the other axes
            of, od = 0, 0  # offsets for accessing fixed values and directions
            # each varying axis can be traversed in one of two directions
            for d_tail in it.product((0, 1), repeat=d_dim - 1):  # dir is the direction for each varying axis
                d = (1, *d_tail)[::-1]  # deduplicate and reverse the direction
                for axes in it.combinations(range(ndim), d_dim):  # axes to vary
                    fm = d_dim * (d_dim + 1) // 2 - sum(axes)  # first dimension with a fixed index
                    dm = min(axes)  # first dimension with a varying index
                    yield [
                        arr[*[fixed[of := 0 if j == fm else of + 1]
                              if j not in axes else
                              (i if d[od := 0 if j == dm else od + 1] else size - (i + 1))
                              for j in range(ndim)]] for i in range(size)
                    ]


lines = get_all_lines(arr)
for line in lines:
    print(line)

The mentioned "deduplication" avoids including each diagonal twice (once in both directions).
Also note that this yields 1d arrays as well as lists of numbers, you can of course cast these appropriately.

Easier syntax is result_1d = [*arr, *arr.T, arr.diagonal(), np.fliplr(arr).diagonal()]

@paime, it can be easily tested, but do you know if the spread operator is more efficient here than the numpy operation?

Considering that you have to ravel afterwards in a for loop, this is already at least as long as using the spread syntax. But even timing it at the result step (i.e. before ravel) versus spread, I obtain 1.99ms vs. 196us for n=1000, and 31.6us versus 4.17us for n=10.

@Grismar This answer does not work, for example, if arr=np.zeros((3,3,3)). The result is a collection of 2d-arrays.

I do suppose this reduces the dimension by 1, so a loop of this method may work out...

You were right @matt, so I've added a more general solution - not exactly concise though.
